# Deploy a Play application as Debian package

Tags: ubuntu, playframework, debian, dpkg

I experienced some issues creating a debian distribution of my Play Application.
deb file is correctly created, and I can install it on Ubuntu 15.04, but start and stop services couldn't be installed:

```
myusr@myhost:~/dev/projects/test/target$ sudo dpkg -i test_0.2_all.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package test.
(Reading database ... 350339 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack test_0.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking test (0.2) ...
Setting up test (0.2) ...
Adding test to autostart using update-rc.d
update-rc.d: error: initscript does not exist: /etc/init.d/test
Failed to start test.service: Unit test.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
test could not be registered or started
```

I also tried to include in the package a "production version" of application.conf and some jvmopts, no luck either (deb file has application.conf version from /conf, not from src/universal/conf -is that the correct path?-, and jvmopts seems to be completely ignored).

This is the build.sbt I'm using in my project:

```
import RjsKeys._

import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.ServerLoader.{SystemV, Upstart}

serverLoading in Debian := SystemV

bashScriptConfigLocation := Some("${app_home}/../conf/jvmopts")

bashScriptExtraDefines += """addJava "-Dconfig.file=${app_home}/../conf/application.config""""

name := """test"""

version := "0.2"

maintainer in Linux := "Me <me@mail.com>"

packageSummary in Linux := "Test"

packageDescription := "Test"

daemonUser in Linux := normalizedName.value

daemonGroup in Linux := (daemonUser in Linux).value

doc in Compile <<= target.map(_ / "none")

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala,JavaServerAppPackaging,DebianPlugin)

linuxPackageMappings in Debian := linuxPackageMappings.value

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

pipelineStages := Seq(rjs, digest, gzip)

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots") 

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  ws,
  filters,
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3.0",
  "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "2.1.3",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.4",
  "org.webjars" % "bootbox" % "4.4.0",
  "org.webjars" % "angularjs" % "1.3.15",
  "org.webjars" % "angular-ui-bootstrap" % "0.13.0",
  "org.webjars" % "nervgh-angular-file-upload" % "1.1.5-1",
  "org.webjars" % "angular-uuid4" % "0.3.0",
  "org.webjars" % "requirejs" % "2.1.14-1",
  "org.webjars" % "d3js" % "3.5.5-1",
  "org.webjars" % "d3-tip" % "0.6.6",
  "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "3.0",
  "ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "master-SNAPSHOT",
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.10.5.0.akka23"
)

scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-target:jvm-1.7",
  "-encoding", "UTF-8",
  "-deprecation",
  "-feature",
  "-unchecked",
  "-Xlint",
  "-Ywarn-adapted-args",
  "-Ywarn-value-discard",
  "-Ywarn-inaccessible",
  "-Ywarn-dead-code",
  "-language:reflectiveCalls"
)

fork in run := false

webJarCdns := Map("org.webjars" -> "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars")
```

Comment: Did you create `application.ini` with a path to `PID`?

Comment: No, I didn't, but PID is created when manually starting the application in the default path.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Failed to start test.service: Unit test.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

... suggests that the package builder is not shipping or correctly installing a [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) unit file or it is not correctly using the sysvinit shim. Can you run the following:

```
dpkg -c test_0.2_all.deb
```

`sudo` isn't required. That will list the file contents of the `.deb`. If we see a `.service` file here, we'd then have to see the package's `.postinst` file to see if it's doing anything silly (or more like missing some initscript setup stanza).

Comment: I have the same problem as the author. Running the above command does not show a .service file.
I am using the latest play version, 2.5.